# MS Access 2016 M:N relationships return multiple columns instead of multiple rows from a JOIN

Tags: join, select, ms-access, query, ms-access-2016

Let's assume a data model like this:

[image: M:N relationship between books and authors.]

Books could have multiple authors as well as authors could have written multiple books.
If a book and its authors are selected by the following statement
(this piece of code is generated by access 2016):

```
SELECT book.book_id, book.title, book.year_of_publication,
       book.pagecount, author.firstname, author.lastname
FROM book 
INNER JOIN (author INNER JOIN link_author_book ON author.auth_id =
            link_author_book.author) 
            ON book.book_id = link_author_book.book
            WHERE (((book.title)="Cassandra: The Definitive Guide, 2nd
            Edition"));
```

the result will be this:
[image: Two rows returned when a book with two authors is selected]

This is perfectly fine and all as expected. Somethimes allthough its a little bit unpractical. In my case I would like to have the different authors not listed in rows but instead in columns. 
It should look like this:

[image]

My question is: is it possible to build something like this in MS Access 2016 and how can I do that? It is not neccessary that this is done in SQL oder VBA or so, I just want to get an output looking like this :)

Thx in advance

PS: If this is a duplicated question I am sorry but at the moment i don't even know how to call/describe my problem so it is a little bit tricky to google for a solution...

Comment: Similar issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98089/how-to-get-the-equivalent-of-array-or-string-group-by-aggregate-functions-in-acc

Comment: Also see [Transform multiple rows into columns with unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898593/transform-multiple-rows-into-columns-with-unique-key/45900941#45900941). Rather than concatenated lists, the answer shows how to use Access SQL transform query to produce multiple columns.  It also has a sample VBA function to produce the same results.